# traefik + caddy > Gateway Timeout

Tags: docker, traefik, caddy

I try to use caddy server with traefik in a simple container. 
Unfortunatly i get a `Gateway Timeout` error when i visite the domain. I can't understand if the error is due to traefik or my container.

My docker-compose file:

```
version: '2'
#
# [ server stack ]
#
services:
    web:
        image: abiosoft/caddy
        container_name: caddy
        restart: unless-stopped
        networks:
            - caddy_network
        ports:
            - 2015:2015
        volumes:
            # app
            - ./localhost:/srv
            # configs
            - ./config/Caddyfile:/etc/Caddyfile
        labels:
            - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:domain.com"
            - "traefik.port=2015"
            - "traefik.backend=domain.com"
            - "traefik.frontend.entryPoints=http,https"
            - "traefik.enable=true"
#
# [ networks definition ]
#
networks:
    caddy_network:
            driver: bridge
```

My caddy file:

```
0.0.0.0:2015
browse
gzip
log stdout
errors stderr
```

For information, the let's encrypt certificat is perfectly generate by traefik.

Any idea? Could it be a problem with the port config?

[edit]
The traefik config:

```
################################################################
# Global configuration
################################################################
defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]
logLevel = "DEBUG"

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
    entryPoint = "https"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.https.tls]

[acme]
email = "admin@domain.com"
storageFile = "/etc/traefik/acme/acme.json"
entryPoint = "https"
OnHostRule = true
onDemand = true

[[acme.domains]]
  main = "domain.com"
  sans = ["docker.domain.com", "traefik.domain.com"] 

################################################################
# Web configuration backend
################################################################

[web]
address = ":8080"

# MD5
[web.auth.basic]
users = ["admin:xxx"]

################################################################
# Docker configuration backend
################################################################

[docker]
endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
domain = "traefik.domain.com"
watch = true
# Tous les conteneurs seront utilisables par Traefik
# Pour qu'il ne le soit pas, il est nécessaire d'ajouter le label "traefik.enable=false" 
# lors de la création du conteneur
exposedbydefault = false
```

Thank you in advance for the help.

jB

Comment: Can you reach caddy on port 2015?

Comment: yes!

`xxx.xxx.xxx.yy:2015` > ok

`domain.com:2015` > ok

but `domain.com` > ko

Comment: Could you share your Traefik configuration file and include a DEBUG level output of your logs please?

Comment: @TimoReimann i have had the traefik configuration. I will add debug info later, sorry.

Comment: My traefik is a bit rusty, but what is `traefik.backend=domain.com` doing and what happens if you remove that?

Comment: @TimoReimann An excerpt of the traefik log :
`time="2017-08-28T06:02:36Z" level=warning msg="Error forwarding to http://172.19.0.2:2015, err: dial tcp 172.19.0.2:2015: i/o timeout" `
`time="2017-08-28T06:02:37Z" level=debug msg="Basic auth success..."` 
`time="2017-08-28T06:02:37Z" level=debug msg="Round trip: http://172.18.0.2:8080, code: 200, duration: 3.883522ms tls:version: 303, tls:resume:false, tls:csuite:c02f, tls:server:docker.domain.com" `

Comment: @BMitch backend configuration is used for load-balancing.

Comment: Just to verify, your traefik container is connected to the caddy_network network, correct? And the ip of your caddy container on that network is 172.19.0.2?

Comment: I was about to ask the same question as @BMitch. Missing the proper network interconnect looks like a likely suspect since Traefik will properly create a forwarding rule through the bind-mounted Docker daemon socket but won't be able to route traffic if it doesn't share the same network.

Comment: Thank you both. It's a silly mistake. I have had the interconnection and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Working solution:

```
version: '2'
#
# [ server stack ]
#
services:
    web:
        image: abiosoft/caddy
        container_name: caddy
        restart: unless-stopped
        networks:
            - traefik_network
        ports:
            - 2015:2015
        volumes:
            # app
            - ./localhost:/srv
            # configs
            - ./config/Caddyfile:/etc/Caddyfile
        labels:
            - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:domain.com"
            - "traefik.port=2015"
            - "traefik.backend=domain.com"
            - "traefik.frontend.entryPoints=http,https"
            - "traefik.enable=true"
            - "traefik.docker.network=traefik_network"
#
# [ networks definition ]
#
networks:
    traefik_network:
        external: true
```

Comment: so you put caddy in the same network of traefik, I had the same problem, if you want to have two networks, one for traefik and other for the service, --network traefik-net --network frontend

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to open the port in that container, I meant this line, it is unnecessary and not recomended:
 ports:
    - 2015:2015